# How to use an image as a frame, and scroll inside? Simulating a phone on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm not sure what this is called, but how do developers accomplish being able to have, say a hollow image of a Nexus phone, and then scroll content inside of it?  It's an ingenious way to simulate how a product will work in real life, so how does one pull this off?

Here's an example, about halfway down the page.

http://grupoweb.upf.edu/innova/q_kly/#step-6

@silversunhunter

I am able to get both images displayed, but the content seems to be completely obscuring the parent div.  I measured the images and the dimensions are correct afaik.

css:

```
.nexus5-frame {
background: url(img/nexus5frame.png);
height:640px;
width:326px;
position: relative;

}

.nexus5-content {
overflow: scroll;
height: 515px;
width: 292px;
position: absolute;
left: 26px;
top 597px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6">
<div id="nexus5-frame">
<div id="nexus5-content">
<img src="img/content.png"/>                
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt and the let us know what you tried and what went wrong. Check out your sample page with a development tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's going on.

Comment: Ah, sorry man, I actually did try to recreate the page (even copy pasting the code) including everything but the CSS (maybe that's what I was missing), and it didn't work, so I decided to ask you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the image as a background image in the parent div. Then a properly measured div inside that is absolutely positioned can be your scrollable content.

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

the phone image is 345px × 661px

```
#main {
    background: url(/filelocation) no-repeat;
    height: 661px;
    width: 345px;
    position: relative;
}
```

the screen is 305x601 (hypothetically)

```
#content {
    overflow: auto; /*this gives us our scroll bar when the content is longer than the div*/
    height: 601px;
    width: 305px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I was able to figure out the answer to my own question. I just made a stupid mistake.  Voting yours as the answer, because you were right.